# Getting error MF_E_STREAMSINKS_FIXED for EVR - Windows Media Foundation

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation

I am implementing an example of media foundation, using below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701605(v=vs.85).aspx

The change that I have did to this example is I have added to Streams by calling.

```
CreateMediaSource(wFile1, &m_pSource_1);
CreateMediaSource(wFile2, &m_pSource_2);

CreateAggregatedSource(m_pSource_1, m_pSource_2, &m_pAggregatedSource);

m_pAggregatedSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pSourcePD);

m_pSession->SetTopology(0, pTopology);
```

Issue that I am facing is, I am getting below error when I run the application:

```
Code: 0xC00D4A3B    
Enum: MF_E_STREAMSINKS_FIXED    
Message: Stream Sinks cannot be added to or removed from this Media Sink because its set of streams is fixed.
```

What I want to implement:
I want to display two video streams in one video renderer using EVR Windows Media Foundation.

Comment: I will provide a working sample when ready. The major problem i think is that you need to negociate media type by hand for the substream, because the mediasession is not able to.

Comment: Thanks for helping out on this, working example will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation on EVR and using Video Mixer to display two video, my conclusion is that evr is not a solution for this (at least on Windows 7).

EVR and Mixer Video simply fail to render two or more video in a simple case. Perhaps a lack of documentation, perhaps...

For me the best way would be to use a custom evr renderer that will do the mixing, without using the design of a mixer video (no need imftransform). The renderer handle the directx things, so it can handle directly the video mixing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - After investigation and experiments I am unable to get the EVR working for video mixing. So though that custom mixer need to be implemented. So started working on mixer. But with custom mixer also not able to render single video steam. Combination used single video stream + custom mixer + default presenter -- Not able to display video stream.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a Custom Video Mixer too, just to see what happens. I will give feedback.

Comment: It is very hard to get the custom mixer get working, even with only one video stream without any mixing. I am trying hard to get custom mixer to play one video stream with EVR + default presenter with no luck.

Comment: For Custom Video Mixer,  my answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946608/media-foundation-custom-mixer-mft-getting-error-mf-e-cannot-create-sink